# How to get the word in my text file and print it 1 by 1 with output of their synonyms?

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the synonyms of the word inputted in my text file. I have 3 inputted words in it.

word.txt:

good

hot

cool

```
import nltk
import os
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
synonyms = []
f = open('filename', "r")
first = f.readline()
for syn in wordnet.synsets(first):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(l.name())
print(set(synonyms))
```

The only output I am receiving is : set()

But, when I remove the 'hot' and 'cool' in my text file, my code is working. I am trying to read it as line by line but I cannot work on that since I am having a problem printing out the first word if I have another input in my text file.

I tried printing the first and second line to know if I can output the good and hot, but the only output that I am seeing is the 'good'

Comment: `first = f.readline()` reads a single line of the file only, so the variable `first` only contains 'good' as a value.

Comment: But I tried inputting another second = f.readline(), the 2nd line is not printing. Also, if I have another input besides from 'good', the 'good' is not reading in my code.

Comment: There is a line-break (`'\n`) after each character, so after printing `good`, your `second` probably took the value of `\n`

Comment: I have other inputs beside from 'good'. If I only have 1 input, then the code is working, but when I have other inputs besides from 'good', based on my example, it is not readable anymore, that's why I only have output of set(), which I don't understand why

Comment: What to do? I tried other method instead of printing out their synonyms, I tried the stemming method and it is weird that every line of my text is printing but when I tried this synonyms, it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is "\n" after every word. When you only have one word, new line is not needed. The solution to this is to use for example f.readline().strip(), which strips the newline character out of the read line. The newline character will make the word look like "hot\n". No synonyms will be found for such a word.

I tested this myself and it started working.

Example code:

```
import nltk
import os
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
synonyms = []
f = open('word.txt', "r")
first = f.readline().strip()
for syn in wordnet.synsets(first):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(l.name())
print(set(synonyms))
```

This example is only for reading the first word of the text file as in your example.

For multiple lines in a file you can do this:

```
import nltk
import os
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
f = open('word.txt', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    synonyms = []
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(line.strip()):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms.append(l.name())
    print(line.strip() + " " + str(set(synonyms)))
```

f.readlines() reads all the lines in the given file and returns a list of lines. If your file has empty lines between words like in your example, you should either remove them or filter them out some other way, otherwise you will read them as empty words.

We had a chat with the guy and here is the answer:

```
import nltk
import os
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
f = open('word.txt', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
print("Synonyms test:")
for line in lines:
    synonyms = []
    print(line)
    answer = input("Answer: ")
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(line.strip()):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms.append(l.name())
    if answer in set(synonyms):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
    print("\nCorrect answers: \n" + " " + str(set(synonyms)))
```

Comment: I tried this code and it is working! I wanna ask, if I add another code below it `second = f.readline().strip()`, and so on, is there any chance that the synonyms for the first one and the second one will be combine? Because my first word in my text file is 'good' and my second word is 'tired', and when I compared it, some word is the same

Comment: Osterholm, how about reading the rest of the inputted word? Like the second or the third one, I noticed that it outputting the same result as the first line.

Comment: I'll reformat my answer to help you with this.

Comment: Osterholm I printed the lines but it is outputting all of my inputs in my text file. What I want is outputting specific line of the text or if possible, outputting it line by line because I am having question and answer where the user need to answer the synonyms of the word based on the wordnet (which I already have code in that) so, the main problem of mine is, printing the text but line by line.

Comment: Like for example 

1. good
answer:
#mycode
2. hot
answer:
#my code

that's why i'm trying out first how can i print the text line by line with their synonyms. sorry if my explanation is bad

Comment: Like I said, the current implementation prints all the synonyms of all the words in total. If you want to print the synonyms per word, you need to put the synonyms = [] inside of the for line in lines loop. and call print(set(synonyms)) inside the same loop, but under the two other loops.

Comment: And if you want to print the word on the same line as the synonyms, you just need to print the word too. For example: print(line.strip() + " " + str(set(synonyms)))

Comment: Can you show me the implementation of this?

Comment: It is now working thank you! But last question, is there any way I can just edit out in your code where which line I want to print? Because I don't know if this algorithm can work in question and answer portion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239567/discussion-between-jimi-osterholm-and-jay).